# li shows result only in first row even i select it form 2nd or third row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ol through jQuery named #cuslist its working on first row only. When I select it on second row the data changed in first row again. I have tried to changed it as class then the same data selected for all rows.(rows are also created dynamically.

```html
<form> 
    <table> 
        <?php $numbers=$_POST['bnumrds']; 
        for($i=1;$i<=$numbers;$i++) { ?> 
            <tr> 
                <td><input type="text" name="cus[]" id="cus" ></input></td> 
                <td> <input type="text" name="del[]" > </input></td> 
                <td> <input type="text" name="rate[]" > </input></td> 
                <td> <input name="rec[]" > </input></td> 
                <td> <input name="pay[]" > </input></td> 
            </tr>
        <?php } ?> 
        <tr> 
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"> </input> </td>
        </tr> 
    </table>
</form>
<div id="cuslist"> // this is sample list. 
    <ol>
        <li>Customer 1</li>
        <li>Customer 2</li>
        <li>Customer 3</li>
        <li>Customer 4</li>
        <li>Customer 5</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
    $('#cus').val($(this).text()); 
    $("#cuslist").fadeOut(); 
});
```

Comment: I guess, it will be easier to help you if you provide your HTML code as well.

Comment: I really hope you are not generating multiple `id="cus"` elements. ID needs to be UNIQUE. one of the kind. Use CSS classes insted... Also edit the question with additional code, do not post in comment. Also if you are adding code that generates dynamic content, at least make a table with dummy data so we can actually see how it looks after its generated... Welcome to SO

Comment: @sajjadsarwar Please note the @ikiK 's comment. Also there are no `<ol>` or `<li>` elements in the HTML code you provided in your comment. This does not correspond to your question.

Comment: I used keyup function on input name="cus[]". which gives me order list #cuslist (customer's code) extracted from database through JQuery. Once I selected, the code inserted into first row. but in second or third rows its show the list correctly  and when I  chose the customer code for 2nd row, its change the first row.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

```js
$(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
    const listItem = $(this);
  
    // Gets an index/position of the current li element
    const listItemIndex = $('li').index(listItem);
  
    // I assume that the number of `input` fields
    // corresponds to the number of `li`
  
    // Gets all inputs with name = "cus[]"
    const allInputs = $('[name="cus[]"]');
  
    // Pick up the input with proper index and
    // set the value from `li`
    allInputs.eq(listItemIndex).val(listItem.text()); 
    
    $("#cuslist").fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form> 
  <table>
    <tr> 
      <td><input type="text" name="cus[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="del[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="rate[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="rec[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="pay[]"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td><input type="text" name="cus[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="del[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="rate[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="rec[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="pay[]"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td><input type="text" name="cus[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="del[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="rate[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="rec[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="pay[]"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td><input type="text" name="cus[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="del[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="rate[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="rec[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="pay[]"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td><input type="text" name="cus[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="del[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="rate[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="rec[]"></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="pay[]"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></input></td>
    </tr> 
  </table> 
</form> 
<div id="cuslist"> 
  <ol>
    <li>Customer 1</li>
    <li>Customer 2</li>
    <li>Customer 3</li>
    <li>Customer 4</li>
    <li>Customer 5</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Demo is here as well - https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/KKzmKNv?editors=1010

Comment: @lhor its show the list in every #cus but not select the li on click

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand.